# Substring searching of text in Google App Engine Datastore entity

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have been working on with Google App Engine. I have found problem with searching sub strings and few other operations. The javax.jdo.Query provides options to set filter as per the need. There are several filters available like contains, inequality operators but I couldn't find any that matches my need.

I am unable to find methods for following:
How to set query filter to

1. search for a substring
2. search by regular expression
3. search by ignore case

Is any of the above 3 operations possible with JDO?

Comment: I see this question was posted in 2012. Are there any new developments that allow us to search this way?

Answer (score 2):

No, these are not possible in the App Engine datastore because they cannot be satisfied with indexes. The App Engine datastore does not execute queries that would require scanning all entities.

For the first option, Full Text Search is probably what you want. For the second, there is no good solution. For the last, you simply need to store a lower- or upper-cased version of the string in the datastore to search against.

Comment: Note that the Search API is completely case-insensitive, so it would solve 1 and 3.

Comment: How can I search for a substring with Full Text Search? Suppose I have a `Document` that has a `name` property with value "banana". How do I query for that document if I only have "ana" to search for?

Comment: @Korneel You can't, unless the string you're searching for is a stemmed version of a word in the document. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @NickJohnson I want to do this to provide search suggestions via AJAX when the user is typing in the search field. I solved this by adding a property to the document with a sentence formed by all possible substrings, e.g. for "banana": "b ba ban bana banan banana a an ana anan anana n na nan nana", and then searching on that property.

Comment: @Korneel In that case, you don't need arbitrary substrings, do you? Just prefixes - which you can do using the regular datastore and inequality matching.

Comment: @NickJohnson I prefer to provide search suggestions based on arbitrary substrings, rather than prefixes only. E.g. when a user types "virginia", "west virginia" should be a suggestion. That's not possible using the regular datastore.

Comment: @Korneel It is if you have a list of _words_ and do prefix matches on them. "Vir" is a prefix of "Virginia", which is one of the words in the list ["West", "Virginia"].

Comment: @NickJohnson am I right in understanding that to do the prefix match against words in the name, you would use a ListProperty with the individual words that sits along side the model's name property?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have make some search on the new FTA from App Engine ? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/

You have to create an index of your data from the datastore then you can use some wildcards to do search on your indexed documents.

But look out this project is for the moment experimental.

EDIT:

An other solution is to use [Whoosh](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/) with a [Backends Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/) on App Engine. Then you create a webservice. and with urlfetch call your backends from your frontends.

Comment: thank you for this link. Will keep in touch with it. But as it is experimental I would refrain from using it right now.

Comment: The other solution is to use Whoosh with a backend.